# How to get file from asp net page with request

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to download file with nodejs !?
I tryed with code:

```
request('https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/captcha/gerarCaptcha.asp', {strictSSL: false}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('captcha.png'));
```

This url:
https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/PessoaJuridica/CNPJ/cnpjreva/captcha/gerarCaptcha.asp
Return an image, how to get this image and save local file ?!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using the request module. To download an image through url you can use

```
var fs = require('fs'),
var request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No work,

```
D:\Fontes_Git\AltaMogiana.Servicos\ValidacaoPessoa\teste.js:6
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
    at Request._callback (D:\Fontes_Git\AltaMogiana.Servicos\ValidacaoPessoa\teste.js:6:38)
    at self.callback (D:\Fontes_Git\AltaMogiana.Servicos\ValidacaoPessoa\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.onRequestError (D:\Fontes_Git\AltaMogiana.Servicos\ValidacaoPessoa\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

After result comment lines:

console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

```
And execute, return exception error again:
internal/streams/legacy.js:57
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8)
```